# how to get description of activity defined in manifest

Tags: android, android-activity

I defined a description for a activity with attribute "android:description"
how to get it programally?

i've tried this code:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
mainIntent.addCategory(CATEGORY);

List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ResolveInfo info = list.get(i);

        String desc = "";
        try {
            desc = res.getString(info.activityInfo.descriptionRes);
        } catch(NotFoundException e) {
            desc = info.activityInfo.name;
        }
}
```

this code throws a NotFoundException.

I have watched the value in debug mode, the param "descriptionRes" did have a int value.

how to get the description? great regards if any help.

Comment: I dont think there is any attribute android:description for Activity . The [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) do not show it. and loadDescription api is only for application

Comment: sorry, it is my fault, there is no attribute "android:description" for Activity tag in manifest